# Generate a script with php or use json

Tags: php, javascript, html, json

I need to know what is better/more efficient, when my page loads I need to load some elements from a database.  Right now I use php to generate the proper JS in a script tag.

It looks something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
canvas = $('#drawn').get(0)
c = canvas.getContext('2d');
    <? foreach ($projectArray[1] as $shape): ?>
    <?
        switch ($shape['type']): 
            case 1: ?>
                c.beginPath();
                c.moveTo(<?=$shape['x_points'][0] ?>, <?=$shape['y_points'][0] ?>);
                <? for ($point = 0; $point < count($shape['x_points'])-1; $point++): ?>
                    c.lineTo(<?=$shape['x_points'][$point] ?>, <?=$shape['y_points'][$point] ?>);
                <? endfor; ?>
                c.stroke();
                <? break;
...
```

This generates a script at the bottom of the page that is really long and looks something like this.

```
script type="text/javascript"> 
canvas = $('#drawn').get(0)
c = canvas.getContext('2d');
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(373, 138);
...
c.lineTo(586, 242);
c.lineTo(588, 243);
c.lineTo(589, 244);
c.stroke();
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(222, 165);
c.lineTo(222, 165);
...
c.lineTo(313, 309);
c.lineTo(261, 309);
c.stroke();
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(81, 110);
c.lineTo(81, 110);
c.lineTo(84, 110);
...
```

As you can see this generates a long script based on an array passed with php based on what I pull from a db.  Deep down in my heart this feels like the wrong way to do it and instead I should encode the array as json and iterate over it as a json object.

Really my question is, is it kosher to generate a script like that or should I use json and what are the advantages of doing it either way?

Comment: JSON. You're repeating `c.lineTo(` like a billion times, so it would be easier on your server to just parse a bunch of numbers and a function delimiter.

Comment: either way you have to run c.lineTo( a lot its just if I run it in a for loop with an object or I run it from a long generated script

Comment: No, what the Blender is saying, is it is much more process intensive to create many strings 'c.lineTo' over and over again (and send that script to the user) rather then just sending the raw data array, and iterating numerically in javascript. The less you do in PHP the better your application will scale with users.

Comment: Ah thank you @greg I was confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest JSON. You can fetch records from DB in an array and simply convert it into JSON, result will be more readable code and even faster PHP side code resulting in faster page load. Now, until and unless you profile your JS side, its hard to predict if the JSON would be faster on client side or not. AFAIK, there is no silver bullet for optimised and fast code.